# AttributeError: 'DatasetDict' object has no attribute 'load_metric'

Tags: python, dictionary, huggingface-transformers

I can't load metrics using DatasetDict.

```
from datasets import Dataset, DatasetDict, load_dataset, load_metric

datasets=DatasetDict({
        "train": Dataset.from_pandas(train),
        "test": Dataset.from_pandas(val)
        })


metric = datasets.load_metric("squad")
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You've already imported `load_metric`, so you can just call it directly:

```
metric = load_metric("squad")
```

As an aside, you should avoid naming objects the same thing as packages you have imported (`datasets` is both the name of the HuggingFace package and the object you're creating). To avoid this confusion and potential accidental shadowing, give more descriptive names to objects you create.

Comment: You are right. I didn't pay attention. Thanks